# How to intercept all the requests for all the controller without HandlerInterceptor in Spring?

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

I have a requirement to intercept all the request in spring 2.5. I don't want to use `HandlerInterceptor` to intercept the request because it requires to configure it with every `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` bean in the context files. Is there another way to intercept all the request without using `HandlerInterceptor`?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a filter and map it to the DispatcherServlet in web.xml. Then you should be able to intercept all request made to Spring MVC.

In short:

1. Create an implementation of javax.servlet.Filter
2. Add the filter to web.xml

   ```
   <filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>mypackage.MyFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   ```

   and then map it to the DispatcherServlet (servlet-name should be the same that is defined for the Spring Dispatcher servlet.

   ```
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
       <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

If you need access to the Spring ApplicationContext in the filter, use the static method

```
   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext()
```